# UDPSendReceiveString example using Arduino Due with ENC28J60 Ethernet Module

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-due, communication, ethernet, enc28j60

I was trying to learn how to use UDP protocol to use in my automation project to send commands to an Arduino Due on ethernet with an ENC28J60 breakout board which I have connected to the Due from SPI pins. I had to use another library called EthernetENC.h to use this module with the Due.
Arduino Code:

```
#include <EthernetENC.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

#define UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE 256

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0xA0, 0x36, 0xBC, 0x30, 0xC1, 0x16
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 137, 205);

unsigned int localPort = 8888;      // local port to listen on

// buffers for receiving and sending data
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];  // buffer to hold incoming packet,
char ReplyBuffer[] = "acknowledged";        // a string to send back

// An EthernetUDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
EthernetUDP Udp;

void setup() {
  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino shields
  //Ethernet.init(5);   // MKR ETH Shield
  //Ethernet.init(0);   // Teensy 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(20);  // Teensy++ 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(15);  // ESP8266 with Adafruit FeatherWing Ethernet
  //Ethernet.init(33);  // ESP32 with Adafruit FeatherWing Ethernet

  // start the Ethernet
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }

  // start UDP
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop() {
  // if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remote = Udp.remoteIP();
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
      Serial.print(remote[i], DEC);
      if (i < 3) {
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    }
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // read the packet into packetBuffer
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);

    // send a reply to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
    Udp.endPacket();
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

Processing 3 Code:

```
 import hypermedia.net.*;

 UDP udp;  // define the UDP object


 void setup() {
 udp = new UDP( this, 6000 );  // create a new datagram connection on port 6000
 //udp.log( true );     // <-- printout the connection activity
 udp.listen( true );           // and wait for incoming message
 }

 void draw()
 {
 }

 void keyPressed() {
 String ip       = "192, 168, 137, 205";  // the remote IP address
 int port        = 8888;    // the destination port

 udp.send("Hello World", ip, port );   // the message to send

 }

 void receive( byte[] data ) {       // <-- default handler
 //void receive( byte[] data, String ip, int port ) {  // <-- extended handler

 for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++)
 print(char(data[i]));
 println();
 }
```

And this is my test setup:
[image]

After I upload the code to the Due the LinkOFF command immediately triggers and Serial.print() prints that "Ethernet cable is not connected." but this is indeed incorrect since this setup worked in other ethernet examples. But other than this message there is nothing on the Serial monitor. On the processing side, the story is even more depressing because simply nothing happens. There is just a small window opening and no matter where a click or press any key on my keyboard no string is being sent or received. I seriously don't know what to do I don't have much experience with UDP and I am trying to learn but the only responsive example in the Arduino library isn't working.

Edit:
I have connected the ENC28J60 directly to my laptop ethernet port and I chose the IP from there which was IPv4 Adress = 192.168.137.1
I also remove the linkOFF() from the original example since it was just using serial monitor for no good.

Comment: do you use a crossed Ethernet cable? try to connect to router and try the basic examples of the Ethernet library (with #include <EthernetENC.h>). best to try as first is the WebClient example

Answer (score 0):

from https://github.com/JAndrassy/EthernetENC/wiki/Examples

> If the `Ethernet.linkStatus()` is invoked too soon, it may return `LinkOFF`. You can do the check in setup() this way:

```
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    delay(500);
    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
  }
```